# hyperledger - explorer: not showing all peers in explorer

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

i have two peers and two organisatio(ri,re).when i try to show the peers in explorer, it always shows 1 peer. its not showing 2 peers.
please find the below config file

```
{
  "name": "eni-network",
  "version": "1.0",
  "client": {
    "tlsEnable": false,
    "adminUser": "admin",
    "adminPassword": "adminpw",
    "enableAuthentication": false,
    "organization": "RmMsp",
    "channel": "samplenetwork",
    "connection": {
      "timeout": {
        "peer": {
          "endorser": "300"
        },
        "orderer": "300"
      }
    }
  },
  "channels": {
    "samplenetwork": {
      "peers": {
        "peer0.rm.ex1.com": {},
        "peer0.re.ex1.com": {}
      },
      "connection": {
        "timeout": {
          "peer": {
            "endorser": "6000",
            "eventHub": "6000",
            "eventReg": "6000"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "organizations": {
    "RmMsp": {
      "mspid": "RmMsp",
      "fullpath": true,
      "adminPrivateKey": {
        "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/rm.ex1.com/users/Admin@rm.ex1.com/msp/keystore/845f6a174e7880f48b2201b2d5fbb15dbc142b9521b9bb23f7e92ee83281b48c_sk"
      },
      "signedCert": {
        "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/rm.ex1.com/users/Admin@rm.ex1.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@rm.ex1.com-cert.pem"
      }
    },
    "ReMsp": {
      "mspid": "ReMsp",
      "fullpath": true,
      "adminPrivateKey": {
        "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/re.ex1.com/users/Admin@re.ex1.com/msp/keystore/dcc66298e88a958688d996786556b0fcdba74dc051d80c459e0e75a2177aad97_sk"
      },
      "signedCert": {
        "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/re.ex1.com/users/Admin@re.ex1.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@re.ex1.com-cert.pem"
      }
    },
    "OrdererMSP": {
      "mspid": "RmOrdererMsp",
      "adminPrivateKey": {
        "path": "/tmp/crypto/ordererOrganizations/rm.orderer/users/Admin@rm.orderer/msp/keystore/cd5770674b623f5f4a2fb218d6d778a224d9c3b464a34b8a9f38153a3542ff5f_sk"
      }
    }
  },
  "peers": {
    "peer0.rm.ex1.com": {
      "tlsCACerts": {
        "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/rm.ex1.com/peers/peer0.rm.ex1.com/tls/ca.crt"
      },
      "url": "grpc://peer0.rm.ex1.com:7051",
      "eventUrl": "grpc://peer0.rm.ex1.com:7053",
      "grpcOptions": {
        "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.rm.ex1.com"
      }
    },
    "peer0.re.ex1.com": {
      "tlsCACerts": {
        "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/re.ex1.com/peers/peer0.re.ex1.com/tls/ca.crt"
      },
      "url": "grpc://peer0.re.ex1.com:8051",
      "eventUrl": "grpc://peer0.re.ex1.com:8053",
      "grpcOptions": {
        "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.re.ex1.com"
      }
    }
  },
  "orderers": {
    "orderer.rm.ex1.com": {
      "url": "grpc://orderer.rm.ex1.com:7050"
    }
  }
}
```

[click here for the image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7PaK.png)

please refer the above image for more information.

docker-compose file

```
 explorerdb.rm.ex1.com:
    image: hyperledger/explorer-db:latest
    container_name: explorerdb.rm.ex1.com
    environment:
      - DATABASE_DATABASE=fabricexplorer
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=hppoc
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - ./createdb.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/createdb.sh
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  explorer.rm.ex1.com:
    image: hyperledger/explorer:latest
    container_name: explorer.rm.ex1.com
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=explorerdb.rm.ex1.com
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=hppoc
      - DATABASE_PASSWD=password
      - DISCOVERY_AS_LOCALHOST=false
    volumes:
      - ./scripts/config.json:/opt/explorer/app/platform/fabric/config.json
      - ./scripts/connection-profile:/opt/explorer/app/platform/fabric/connection-profile
      - ./crypto-config:/tmp/crypto
      - walletstore:/opt/wallet
    command: sh -c "sleep 16&& node /opt/explorer/main.js && tail -f /dev/null"
    ports:
      - 8090:8080

peer0.rm.ex1.com:
    container_name: peer0.rm.ex1.com
    extends:
      file: /opt/shared/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.rm.ex1.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.rm.ex1.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.rm.ex1.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.re.ex1.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=RmMsp
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couch.peer0.rm.ex1.com:5984
    volumes:
      - /opt/rm/creds/peers/peer0.rm.ex1.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - /opt/rm/creds/peers/peer0.rm.ex1.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
          - peer0.rm.ex1.com:/var/hyperledger/production
ports:
      - 7051:7051

peer0.re.ex1.com:
    container_name: peer0.re.ex1.com
    extends:
      file: /opt/shared/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.re.ex1.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.re.ex1.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.re.ex1.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.rm.ex1.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=ReMsp
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couch.peer0.re.ex1.com:5984
    volumes:
      - /opt/re/creds/peers/peer0.re.ex1.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - /opt/re/creds/peers/peer0.re.ex1.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
          - peer0.re.ex1.com:/var/hyperledger/production
ports:
      - 8051:8051
```

it has to show two peers:
    1) peer0.ri.ex1.com
    2) peer0.re.ex1.com

but its showing only : peer0.ri.ex1.com.

Any leads would be appreciated!

[docker ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzlxo.png)

i have checked explorer log file..the second organisation(ReMsp) is empty.please find the below reference

```
 orderers: { RmOrdererMsp: { endpoints: [Array] } }, 
peers_by_org: { RmMsp: { peers: [Array] }, ReMsp: { peers: [] } } }.
```

its look like config.json problem. Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check in docker-compose file if you have implemented **GOSSIP protocol** there on peer section. For Reference -

```
peer0.org3.bc4scm.de:
    container_name: peer0.org3.bc4scm.de
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org3.bc4scm.de
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org3.bc4scm.de:11051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:11051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org3.bc4scm.de:11052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:11052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org3.bc4scm.de:11051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org3.bc4scm.de:12051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org3MSP
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.bc4scm.de/peers/peer0.org3.bc4scm.de/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.bc4scm.de/peers/peer0.org3.bc4scm.de/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer0.org3.bc4scm.de:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 11051:11051

peer1.org3.bc4scm.de:
    container_name: peer1.org3.bc4scm.de
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org3.bc4scm.de
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org3.bc4scm.de:12051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:12051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.org3.bc4scm.de:12052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:12052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org3.bc4scm.de:12051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org3.bc4scm.de:11051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org3MSP
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.bc4scm.de/peers/peer1.org3.bc4scm.de/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/supplier.bc4scm.de/peers/peer1.org3.bc4scm.de/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer1.org3.bc4scm.de:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
    - 12051:12051
```

For example you could have a look in to the above mentioned peer -

peer0.org3.bc4scm.de : 
**- CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org3.bc4scm.de:11051
- CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org3.bc4scm.de:12051**

peer1.org3.bc4scm.de :

**- CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org3.bc4scm.de:12051
- CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org3.bc4scm.de:11051**

@Change your file accordingly your network.

**Update --**

```
peer0.rm.ex1.com:
    - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.re.ex1.com:8051

peer0.re.ex1.com:
    - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.rm.ex1.com:7051
```

Comment: Hi Artho, thanks for the reply. Already i have mentioned gossip protocol in peers, i have updated the peers code in above snippet. still  the second peer is not appearing in explorer. is it something to do with config.json?

Comment: could you check once if all your peers are up and running - docker ps -a

Comment: yes, all of the them are running, please verify the image which i have updated above.

Comment: As I could see in your shared ss, there is 2 peers and it looks like port is not open for peer0.rmi.***** meanwhile port(8051) is open for peer0.rena.****, thatswhy only 1 peer is accessible.

Comment: i have opened the port but still its not apperaing in explorer...please refer the above peer code for open port.

Comment: check my updated code section, CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP is not correct in your docker-compose file.

Comment: yeah i have updated the bootstrap part. but still second peer not showing up in explorer ....is it something to do with config.json?

Comment: i have checked explorer log file..the second organisation is empty.please find the . below reference
 orderers: { RmOrdererMsp: { endpoints: [Array] } },
  peers_by_org: { RmMsp: { peers: [Array] }, ReMsp: { peers: [] } } }.

its look like config.json problem.

Comment: org - ReMsp peer have joined the samplenetwork channel or not ?

Comment: i'm not sure how to check that.. can you help me to get the commands!! .
i was trying to get the channal info via swagger. but it throwing an error "TypeError: Failed to fetch ."  using swagger ui "http://localhost:8080/api-docs/#/Channel/fetchChannelInfo"

Comment: use -  docker exec -it <container_id> bash , to go inside peer container and then use - peer channel list, command , joined channel  will list there.

Comment: thanks, i just checked both peers are joined in channel still its not appearing in explorer

Comment: @sharif2008 Not yet

Comment: Sad to know it :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following changes:

- You also need to add CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS to both of peers because you've changed the default listen port (7051).

  peer0.rm.ex1.com:
    CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051

  peer0.re.ex1.com:
    CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8051
- You can not specify peer on other org to CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP (Please refer [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/d3a7fa8f3156889851d665a721feca4139c94a2d/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L77) in detail). You don't have any options except its own URL.

  peer0.rm.ex1.com:
    CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.rm.ex1.com:7051

  peer0.re.ex1.com:
    CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.re.ex1.com:8051
- FWIW, as long as see your environment, you don't need to differentiate port number of each peer node(You don't need change default port number(7051). You only need to be unique when you access peer nodes from outside of docker environment, by differentiating docker-compose port mapping).